# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded every time

Tags: php

every time my php script sends me "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". Is there any way to show the custmize error to visitor instead of this big error message. i mean can we use our own error message at the place of this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an endless loop somewhere. You could debug the PHP on your own machine (adding debug printing inside, etc.)

Comment: but how to debug the php on my own machine

Comment: Install a web server and a PHP environment on it. It could be worthwhile to install a Linux distribution (because most web servers are Linux machines).

Comment: but i have checked all of my loops they are absolutely right. is there any other wrong with me. and the another problem is that i am getting data using file_get_contents and it is not providing all results.

Comment: I have no idea. Don't forget that loops may be hard to find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Also, it may not be an endless loop... it may just be a loop that is taking a really long time to process (longer than the 30 second timeout). Are you processing a lot of data or generating a lot of output in any of your loops? That might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this in the top of your php script

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

this means your script has unlimited time to execute the script, but you can limit it to x seconds, if you replace the 0 with a number of seconds like 500. But if you have a bug, like a endless loop the script would never stop and maybe your server could die if 100's visitor hit the script.

Answer (score 0):

pin down your endless loop by inserting

```
die('got here...');
```

at top and move it downwards in your script, you'll find your problematic code quite quickly. Real debugging is smoother but needs some setting up.

A functional php script should normally take less than a second to execute.

regards,

///t